# Javascript read HTML tags

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net

I have a problem and I don't know how to fix it after sometime now, I really need help

So I have `asp:GridView`, in my DB i am saving text (In English column) with HTML tags, on `DataBound` event I am using `Context.Server.HtmlDecode(encoded);` so it is displayed perfectly

[image: This is Grid View]

But problem is, that also on that event, I am creating `OnClick` event for that cell ... calling javascript function, and sending parameters to it, it looks like this

```
ChangeTranslationText('English',
'<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-style:italic;">Stavi dole
</span><span style="font-weight: bold;">neki text<br><br><br>Hvala na paznji!
<br><br>Mozes Z da stavis<br><br>Ali Z<br><br>Hvala<br></span></div> '
,'56');return false;
```

Now in function I am trying that my javascript read that HTML and format my text as it looks like in GridView ...

```
function ChangeTranslationText(Language, Text, Control) {

        document.getElementById("MainContent_txtChangeLanguage").value = Language;

        var el = $('<div></div>');
        el.html(Text);
        document.getElementById("MainContent_txtTranslationText").innerHTML = el.text();

        document.getElementById("MainContent_hfControl").value = Control;

        $('#ModalChangeTranslate_Fade').modal('show');
    }
```

And I can't format it as I don't know how ... this is best I got so far

[image]

Can you help me and advice me how can Javascript read that HTML and keep format like it is in GridView cell?

Answer (score 0):

I made a test here and saw two things:

`var el = $('<div></div>');` was throwing `$ is not defined`. You probably have jquery library in your project, but you actually dont need to declare this  `el` variable. You can use it like you did before:

```
document.getElementById("MainContent_txtTranslationText").innerHTML = Text;
```

Another thing was your `Text` parameter. Not sure if the line breaks is only in the question, but, when we have a `string` in javascript, it must be on the same line. You can't break lines with "enter". You will need to concatenate the `strings` to do that, like this:

```
var html = '<div style="text-align: center;"><span style="font-style:italic;">Stavi dole' +
'</span><span style="font-weight: bold;">neki text<br><br><br>Hvala na paznji!' + 
'<br><br>Mozes Z da stavis<br><br>Ali Z<br><br>Hvala<br></span></div>';
```

Comment: Sorry for line breaks with "enter", I just did it on question, just for better visibility. If i go document.getElementById("MainContent_txtTranslationText").innerHTML = Text; , my textarea will just write string, with HTML markups, it won't format text as it is in GridView